# Remove frames from animation android

Tags: android, android-animation, animationdrawable

I have been trying out frame animation in android. I am able to add new frames, by using the following command

```
     animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable
```

Is there a way where I can flush all the frames, start fresh again.?

Comment: What's `android` here?

Comment: sorry. its the animation name. I will change it to animation.

Answer (score 1):

To remove all frames you can call:

```
android = new AnimationDrawable();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't _remove_ all frames, it just instantiate a new object.

Comment: it instantiate a new AnimationDrawable with will have 0 frames, isnt it the same? why it doesnt fit your needs?

Comment: can you please suggest a better way if you have? @abforce

Comment: Looking at the docs it looks that there is no way to remove frames from an AnimationDrawable

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan I've just looked at docs, seems there's no way so far to remove a frame. However you should reconsider your requirement or use Nanoc's way, anyway.

Comment: I am, but there are few fix to be done, if we are using that way and am working on it.